# I hit my head leaving a large commercial building and the security guards asked for my ID, phone number, and email - why?

Tags: liability

Today I was leaving a large commercial building (~15 stories) and walked straight into the glass surrounding a revolving door, thinking that the opening was not so narrow.

I went to the security desk and asked to use the bathroom to clean myself up. The person I talked to gave me some bandages and let me use the bathroom to clean the blood off my face. Another security guard then took down my phone number, email, name, and asked for an ID. Why did they take this info down? Are they going to contact me?

Comment: I understand why you might assume this is a legal question but we don't know enough to share that assumption.

Comment: So they can send you a check for your pain, suffering, and medical expenses?  (JK)  I agree with jqning: Do you have a legal question?  If you want to know why they did that then why not ask *them*?

Comment: I think they intend to sue you for the damages you caused by bleeding all over their shiny glass entrance

Comment: Your question as it stands now would really best have been answered on the spot. But I agree with the others, you might want to reformulate your question to make it a legal one. Maybe you wonder if you have a claim against the company for damages? Maybe you want to know if the guard was allowed to get that info from you?

Comment: It gives them a record that something happened, and in general what it was. This is probably for at two reasons, to maintain accident records for the building, and if you decide to sue, there is a record of what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I would *guess* this is protection in case *you* try to sue *them*.

When you come claiming concussion, blinding headaches and permanent disability, they can say "No, our records show you needed a band aid and an aspirin".

Comment: Does giving a band aid and aspirin at the time of injury preclude or weigh against evidence that a person suffered concussion, headaches, or disability? I don't think it does at all.